# Looking for crypto with derived keys?

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for cryptographic algorithm or combination of them.

Basically I need an algorithm, which can generate private key and for this key can be computed multiple keys based on some seed. So a different seed would generate a different line of keys and so on. Does such an algorithm (or set of algorithms) exist?

I think something like this is used for in PS3 games, where consoles have some master key and games are encrypted with various public keys.

Does something like this really exists or I am completely wrong and this isn’t possible at all?

**EDIT:**

I will try to explain scenario I need to solve.

I have a data-file I need to protect against unauthorized reading attempts. I considered using the RSA public/private concept for that, but I need something  where I can have one single public key for reading.

I need to change that key every time and that’s where I want to create some key derivations from, which are dynamically generated.

It looks similar like RSA tokens, which generate new pin code each time. I need something like this. Just $1 * PrivateKey \rightarrow N * PublicKeys$.

Additionally, it would be great if I could sign it with a certificate, but that’s not so important to me as having the ability to hide the data from curious eyes… that’s definitely more important to me.

I hope this description helps…

Comment: _Encryption_ makes it impossible for an adversary to understand data exchanged/stored, after it has been modified towards that goal by anyone with the public key; only the holder of the (private) key can recover the original data from the data exchanged/stored. $\text{ }$ _Signature_ makes it possible for anyone with the public key to verify that data has been approved by the holder of the private key, and was not subsequently modified.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I need more encryption to make them unreadable, after that i can sign them with certificate, but more important is to encrypt data.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Who shall encrypt and who shall decrypt and why do you need multiple encryption(?) keys.

Comment: Its for my experimental client app. Encrypting and Decrypting is made on client application. And i want to have posibility to encrypt data flow block with different keys.  I have already found DUKPT scheme, which is more or less what i need. Or are there similar schemes i could check?